# EtG formation outside the liver

Tags: organic-chemistry, biochemistry

Ethyl glucuronide (EtG) is formed by conjugation with glucuronic acid catalyzed by the enzyme UDP-glucuronosyltransferase.

My question: Is it possible for EtG to form spontaneously in a urine sample that contains a small amount of ethanol?

Answer (score 1):

No, because the equilibrium for the simple reaction lies on the side of the reactants:

$$\ce{Ethanol + glucoronic acid <<=> Ethyl glucuronide + H2O}\tag{1}$$

The reaction works enzymatically inside the cell because glucuronic acid first reacts with UTP, turning it into a mixed anhydride (phosphate of UDP bound to carboxylic acid of glucuronic acid) plus inorganic phosphate.

$$\ce{UTP + glucoronic acid <=>> UDP-glucuronide + phosphate} \tag{2}$$

Then, the enzyme swaps UDP for ethanol or other molecules.

$$\ce{Ethanol +  UDP-glucuronide <=>> Ethyl glucuronide + UDP}\tag{3}$$

The net difference between hypothetical reaction (1) and the two step process (2) and (3) is the hydrolysis of UTP, a reaction with a negative Gibbs energy of reaction (i.e. equilibrium constant larger than one):

$$\ce{UTP + H2O -> UDP + phosphate} \tag{4}$$

So the formation of UPD and phosphate from UTP drives the two step reaction (it is a coupled reaction).

Attaching glucuronic acid makes molecules more water-soluble, helping to excrete them in the urine [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glucuronide).

Comment: Karsten, these reactions are spontaneous only because of the energetic contribution from $\mathrm{UTP \rightarrow UDP + P_i}$, right?

Comment: @hBy2Py yes, right (Gibbs energy contribution)

Comment: See edit - I tried to clarify the differences between the urine and liver contexts a bit. Please revise or revert as you desire.